# Conjectured congruence $A048852(n-1) \equiv p_n - p_{n-1} \pmod{4}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, oeis

Let $p_n$ denote the n-th prime. OEIS [A048852](https://oeis.org/A048852)
is shortly defined as "Difference between b^2 (in c^2=a^2+b^2) and product of successive prime pairs".

Numerical evidence for $3 \le n \le 52$, all of the B-file 
except the first terms suggests:

$$
A048852(n-1) \equiv p_n - p_{n-1} \pmod{4}
$$

Is the congruence true?

What is more detailed definition of A048852 to check more terms?

Comment: I do not understand the definition. What are $a,b,c$ in $c^2=b^2+a^2$? How are they related with prime pairs?

Comment: @FedorPetrov I don't understand it too. They appear to come from this crossreferenced sequence: https://oeis.org/A048851

Comment: From $n=2$ on A048851 is just the sequence of $p_{n-1}^2+p_n^2$

Comment: And in fact A048852 seems to be $p_n^2-p_np_{n-1}$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The last comment will solve it, it holds for all sequences of odd numbers. Your indices appear off by one compared to the OEIS definition starting from 0.

Comment: Yes you are right, I did not notice offset zero, A048852$(n)$ is $p_{n+1}^2-p_{n+1}p_n$. With A048851 I think $p_{n-1}^2+p_n^2$ is correct, offset is 1 there.